# Photoshop CC: Problems with text selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, layers, creative-cloud

I have tried to solve an issue for hours without luck, so I have decided to write for help. The main problem is that when I am creating Mock-Ups with the new Photoshop CC, every time I try to create a new text by clicking somewhere with the Type Tool, the nearest existing texts gets selected.

If I want to create a new text layer by clicking on screen, I have to click outside the canvas. This is quite annoying, as even when I am trying to edit a text by clicking on it, if there is a text in a upper layer that is close (not overlaping) it gets selected instead, so I have to hide layers to be able to edit some of the texts.

It is really annoying, do you guys know why is this happening? I have tried to search for a option or setting I have enabled but haven't found anything.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi iBigata, Welcome to GD.SE! Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing SHIFT while clicking to create the new text layer.

If you are having trouble editing an existing text layer double click the [T] icon in the layers panel beside the corresponding layer to edit that text in particular.

Here is a quick demonstration : https://youtu.be/8pM4yUgcZkE

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I didn't had any problem untill I upgraded to CC, but with this tips I can work with less "annoyance". Thank you again!